# update_post_meta not working in a loop

Tags: plugin-development, post-meta

I am new with plugin development and i have one issue while updating post meta.
I have to create checkbox for each user but while updating post update_post_meta is not working for all checkboxes. Values are correct but these are not updating in database.
Here is my code.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
global $post;
$all_users = get_users();
foreach($all_users as $user){
$my_meta_box_check = "my_meta_box_check".$user->ID;
$chk = isset( $_POST[$my_meta_box_check] ) && $_POST[$my_meta_box_check] ? 'on' : 'off';
update_post_meta( $post_id, $my_meta_box_check, $chk );
}
}
```

This code is working for few check boxes but not for all. I will really appreciate your help because i am trying to fix this issue for many hours but nothing working.

Comment: Maybe this plugin will help you to handle data from metabox https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But i could not use plugin because i have already lot of other functionality related to these checkboxes.

Comment: You are not setting `$post_id` variable. You need to add `$post_id = $post->ID;` after `global $post`

Comment: $post_id is already in functions parameters and i have also tried with your suggestion but still the same problem.

Comment: How many users are there? I wonder if get_users() just returns you first 10 or something... What about adding `paged` param to it to make it 100% sure it gets all users?

`get_users(array('number' => 10000))`

Comment: You can try printing `echo "update_post_meta( $post_id, $my_meta_box_check, $chk );"'` to see which calls are actually made

Comment: It is returning all users and i have already create these  check boxes (via add_meta_box)using same loop.

Comment: Try to print a line for every function call... also you can print result of update_post_meta function to see if that returns `true` ...

Comment: I have already do this and it is returning correct value for post id, key and value.
post id:604 key:my_meta_box_check27 val:on
post id:604 key:my_meta_box_check12 val:on
post id:604 key:my_meta_box_check21 val:on
post id:604 key:my_meta_box_check23 val:on
post id:604 key:my_meta_box_check22 val:on
post id:604 key:my_meta_box_check26 val:on